# How to make a background image slowly move upwards

Tags: xml, android-studio, kotlin

I'm using Android Studio, Kotlin, and my activity files are coded in xml.

---

I'm looking to have the background in my app slowly move upwards.

https://youtu.be/_mg5WrvZr3g?t=26

^ Sorta like this but with only one layer moving.

This is how I have my background image being set in my activities xml file:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background01tilable"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
```

And this is what my drawable for the image looks like:

```
<bitmap
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/background01"
    android:tileMode="repeat"
    android:scaleType="center"
    android:layout_width="10dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    />
```

How would I go about make a slow moving background image?

Comment: Instead of moving it as background put things in a framelayout and make bg's as images and move them with basic animations

Comment: I need the background to be tiled though and infinitely "scroll"

Comment: you can use gif as background

Comment: I was hoping to not have to use a gif due to performance concerns

Comment: Why don't you want to use programmatic way of moving `ImageView`s or `<MotionLayout>`? What do you mean by "scroll"? Do you want to have a background in `RecylerView` or `ScrollView`? In this case how a background will animate like?

Comment: I want the background to slowly move, I don't want it to be tied to a a scroll or animation. I want it to be similar to the attached video. Also I'm not ruling out "programmatically" as that would obviously be the way to go.